# How to apply subdivision surface modifier to this cube without artifacts?

Tags: python, modifiers, geometry, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm trying to make a simple ramp shape with a cube. I applied a bevel modifier to a single edge, then another bevel to all edges, and finally a subsurf modifier to make it smooth. However, the subsurf causes artifacting. I know this is due to the underlying geometry, but I don't know what the most efficient way of fixing this is.

I'm trying to understand the flow of this shape because I'm working on a python script to make it for me (for learning purposes). Currently I've just disabled the subsurf modifier, as it looks okay without it. In the future though, I want to figure out how to produce that shape without artifacts.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be OK with just the two *Bevel Modifiers* - the first one with the weighted edge (highlighted below), and the second with default settings. Shade Smooth afterwards to make it smooth without the need for a *subdivision Surface Modifier* (which almost certainly will cause artifacting under these conditions).

[image: Bevels]

Comment: That is definitely not a bad result... I know that I can do that via scripting as well, so that's good. Cheers!